# How can I be reminded about missing attachments in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I would like to be reminded about missing attachments in a sent email in Inbox by Gmail, e.g. when writing the words "attachment", "attached" in the body but actually forgetting to attach any file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019.